intellisense vscode became slow after deleting files
I have a problem with a React Ts 18 project using Vite.
Vscode intellisense was working fine until I deleted some .ts and .tsx files. They were normal components and some Zustand stores that were not used, from there the Intellisense takes a few seconds to give me the references of my files or components. I have checkout in the commit where I deleted those files and the intellisense is slow, if I checkout in a previous commit it works correctly.
NOTE: The intellisense loads normally again if I let it load for a couple of minutes.
I have tried clearing cache, restarting TS server, reinstalling dependencies, etc.
1
